# Using Sqlite3 Library in MinGW windows

Tags: c, sqlite, gcc, cmake, mingw

I'm developing a cmake project. I need to use sqlite.

**System: Clion + MinGw-cmake + Windows 11**

I tried to include sqlite3.h.

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

There will be error like this:

> fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory

Added sqlite3 package in cmake.

```
find_package (SQLite3)

if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries (tutorial ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)
```

> Could NOT find SQLite3 (missing: SQLite3_INCLUDE_DIR SQLite3_LIBRARY)

Finally Downloaded `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3ext.h` and placed them in project directory and included it.

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

Now there in new error:

> undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'

Please help me.

Comment: The same problem here:/

Comment: The simplest way to use SQLite from C or C++ is to include the "sqlite3.c" amalgamation in your source, and include "sqlite3.h". (You don't need "sqlite3ext.h").

Comment: Can you elaborate? How to get this files? can you provide a link?

Comment: You should probably be using some sort of package manager to manage the dependencies, such as Conan. There is a Conan plugin for CLion; see [Getting Started with the Conan CLion Plugin](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/05/getting-started-with-the-conan-clion-plugin/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the answer.

Just as **@MarkBenningfield** said in comments.

> The simplest way to use SQLite from C or C++ is to include the "sqlite3.c" amalgamation in your source, and include "sqlite3.h". (You don't need "sqlite3ext.h")

You should download zip file from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-amalgamation-3410000.zip) and extract `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` to you project main path.

Then include `sqlite3.h` in the head of your `main.c` file:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

**The final and most important step. Add `sqlite3.c` to your build command or your `CMAkeLists.txt` file:**

```
add_executable(YourProjectName main.c sqlite3.c)
```

Done!